# Web push notification token changes in Safari on macOS (16.5.2)

Tags: django, firebase, safari, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I have successfully implemented web push notifications on my website using Firebase Admin SDK. The notifications work flawlessly on Windows and Chrome on macOS. However, I encountered an issue with Safari on macOS 16.5.2.

The problem is that every time I quit Safari, the notification token changes, and as a result, users do not receive new notifications when they reopen the browser. Strangely, this behavior doesn't occur in Chrome on macOS.

Does anyone have any insights into why this might be happening?

This is my getToken code, I extracted it from the docs.

```js
const token = localStorage.getItem('firebaseToken')
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'my vapid key'})
.then((currentToken) => {

if (currentToken != token) {
 console.log(currentToken)
 sendTokenToServer(currentToken)
else {
 console.log('Already saved');
}).catch((err) => {
 console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried listening to the `pushsubscriptionchange` event and sending the new subscription to the backend? You can take inspiration from the code snippet in this post: https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2021/01/web-push-error-410-the-push-subscription-has-expired-or-the-user-has-unsubscribed/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.